# USB ports not working

Tags: usb, hardware, puppy-linux

Ok, got a Puppy Linux Wary 5.3. running on an old laptop with USB ports.

Now, here's the strange part ... none of them work.  When I stick in a USB-stick there's no reaction.  Still, `lsusb` lists them:

```
# lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
```

and even stranger ... when I plugin a PCMCIA Card Bus USB 2.0 adapter, those work:  every one of the four adapter USB slots DO recognize the USB stick.

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This was the case, too, when some strange operating system called win-something was installed on this laptop.  Gee, I can't even remember, it wasn't Solaris.

Any suggestions how to check if it's just a hardware problem?  How to fix this?

Further details:  The laptop is an Acer Travelmate 2301LM.

---

**Update after Salton feedback**: "Onboard USB supports only USB 1.0"
I ran `lspci -v` to verify the speed of the lsb ports ...

Three controllers use `uhci_hcd` module indicating USB 1.x.  One controller uses `ehci_hcd`, though, indicating USB 2.0.

Mhmm, not sure how to interpret this info?  There are only three USB ports on this laptop.  None seem to use the USB 2.0 controller.

```
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0064
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 6
    I/O ports at 1820 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0064
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 6
    I/O ports at 1840 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0064
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 6
    I/O ports at 1860 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0064
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at e0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=0080
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
```

Comment: Does "no reaction" include that `dmesg` shows nothing new when you plug something in?

Comment: it looks like your on board USB ports support only 1.0. The PC card allow you to connect external hardware where you are able to connect 2.0 USB adapter.

Comment: @Salton: but that should in most cases just mean the devices can't negotiate the higher speeds or other 2.0 features. (Or was that something that was only introduced in USB1.1?) 
Or course, it's entirely possible that not being downwards compatible with USB 1.0 saves half a penny in production...

Comment: Sometimes you can configure the USB speed/feature mode in the computer's BIOS. I'd take a look in there to make sure everything is enabled first.

Comment: @slm The BIOS didn't list any options on USB. Actually, hardly any options on anything, this laptop is ancient. Checked the BIOS version, too and Acer lists it as the most up to date one (Bios Ver. 3A07). So, no settings possible via BIOS.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz Nope, `dmesg` output is identical when the USB-stick is plugged in or not.

Comment: @Salton, ok, updated my post to verify port speed. Not sure about the result.